# Highlighting un-commited code in vim for git

Tags: git, vim

Is there some vim plugin that performs the following?

When opening a source file (that is tracked by git), highlight the un-committed source codes.

Comment: tpope/vim-fugitive, `:Gdiff` (but it will open vimdiff layout).

Comment: Why would you want to do that in your text editor when there's `$ git diff`, tig and a bunch of graphical client.

Comment: Because I want to see the difference while I'm editing the code.

Comment: You don't see the difference, you see that there's a difference which is entirely *different* and a lot less useful because you will need a diff to see the actual difference. You should use `$ git diff` directly instead of polluting your config with another plugin.

Comment: Actually, in my case, all the differences are the newly added lines (no edition inside a line). So this is quite good in my use case. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, opinions aside, you can try [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) or [vim-signify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify) which show you changed lines in the sign column.

Comment: Here's the correct [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) link.

Comment: @AndyStewart, what a stupid mistake! Thanks for spotting it.